# libfaac: Queue input is backward in time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, libav, transcoding, libfaac

I am using libav along with libfaac to encode audio into aac. 
following is the logic:

```
frames[n]
i = 0 ;
while (there are frames)
{ 
  cur_frame =  frames[i];
  av_encode_audio(frame, ...., &frame_finished);
  if( frame_finished )
  {
     i++;
  }
}
```

but I am getting this annoying warning for few frames "queue input is backward in time !"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very simple, you are not supposed to pass the same frame again to the libfaac,
so even if the frame_finished is not 1 you should still go to the next frame.

it should be as follows:

```
frames[n]
i = 0 ;
while (there are frames)
{ 
  cur_frame =  frames[i];
  av_encode_audio(frame, ...., &frame_finished);
  i++;
}
```